# Why is "sort" sorting ALL arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have this (in Javascript):

```
function f(n){
   var arr = (''+n).split();
   var sortedArr = arr;
   sortedArr.sort();
}
```

When I return arr and sortedArr, they are both sorted.  Why is this?  Shouldn't the .sort method only sort sortedArr here?

Comment: When you copy an array or object like this when just assigning it you are referencing the same array. It is not a true copy, it points at the same array.

You can use the spread operator from ES6 to copy the array:

`var sortedArr = [...arr];`

Comment: `arr === sortedArr`

Comment: Nicely explained @rymdmaskin, think of it like putting a name tag on a locker, what you're doing is putting two different name tags on the same locker. EDIT, or you can do `arr.slice()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Array.prototype.slice, will fix the issue.

```
function f(n){
   var arr = (''+n).split();
   var sortedArr = arr.slice();
   sortedArr.sort();
}
```

#### Edit

**The reason is that arrays and objects in javascript are references and hence mutable.**

When you assign, `sortedArr=arr;`
You're actually copying the reference not the values. i.e. like 
if arr is stored at address 1267, then sortedArr will also point to 1267 now, instead of copying the values at different location.

While, when we are doing `sortedArr=arr.slice();` it is actually copying the values to other location suppose 1367 and hence pointing sortedArr to a different storage location.

**And I guess its quite evident that, in case the values are copied by reference, changing the values through any reference will reflect a change in the other one as well.**

Comment: Although this will fix the issue, could you include the reason **why** this issue is occurring, although it's been mentioned in the comments, answers are more stable and are less likely to be deleted/removed, unlike comments.

Comment: @George Edited the answer with much clarification. Do let me know if you still feel the need of more clarification :)

Answer (score 1):

Kindly look up the difference between primitive data types and referential data types. Objects are referential data types. (Array is an object). If u expecting to create a new copy, then u should use:-

let new_obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objname))

- OR -

let new_arr = arr1.slice()

See this example:-

```
let a1 = [1, 123, 10, 20, 30];
let a2 = a1.slice();
a2[0] = 0;
console.log(a1, a2);
console.log(a1.sort(), a2.sort());
```

Also, take care while passing referential data types as params. U will run into this problem again.

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objname))` This is bad advice, what if the array contains functions? Just stick with the `slice()` or spread operator.

Comment: Ye, well it does only shallow copy. I believe Lodash has a deepclone() / clone() method, or something like that. to do that. moreoften than not, shallow copy is what u require. But for some reason a deep clone needs to be done, then use Lodash's helper methods.